# How to select subcategory items with a category name in php MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, yii, yii2, yii-components

This is my Code I am using yii framework.

how do I show all the Sub category with category_name for the Category table ?

[This is the Category Table with the items][1]

[This is the Sub Category Table with the items it has the cat_id and merchant_id from the Category Table][2]

[And This is What i want it to show but i don't how to get the category_name form the Category table][3]

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZlrx.png][1]

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKyhb.png][2]

```
Name                        Categery Name
```

1. Sub Cat Testing-----------------Category Name - Not Showing
2. Sub cat 2 testing---------------Category Name - Not Showing

   ```
   public function subCategoriesList()
       {

       $mtid=Yii::app()->functions->getMerchantID();
       $slug=$this->data['slug'];
       $stmt="
       SELECT sub_id, cat_id, merchant_id, sub_category_name FROM
       {{sub_categories}}
       WHERE
       merchant_id='".Yii::app()->functions->getMerchantID()."'
       ORDER BY cat_id DESC
       ";
       $connection=Yii::app()->db;
       $rows=$connection->createCommand($stmt)->queryAll();            
       if (is_array($rows) && count($rows)>=1){
           foreach ($rows as $val) {        


               /*$date=date('M d,Y G:i:s',strtotime($val['date_created']));                    
               $date=Yii::app()->functions->translateDate($date);*/
               $date=FormatDateTime($val['date_created']);

               if (!empty($val['photo'])){
                   $img=Yii::app()->request->baseUrl."/upload/$val[photo]";
                   $photo="<img class=\"uk-thumbnail uk-thumbnail-mini\" src=\"$img\" >";  
               } else $photo='';



                           $cat_id=Yii::app()->functions->getCategories(1);


               $feed_data['aaData'][]=array(
                 $chk,stripslashes($val['sub_category_name']).$option,
                 stripslashes("Category Name - Not Showing"),


                 $photo,
                 "$date<br/><span class=\"tag ".$val['status']."\">".t($val['status'])."</span>"
               );
           }
           $this->otableOutput($feed_data);
       }           
       $this->otableNodata();
   }
   ```

Comment: Try to edit the question. Third image is not uploaded correctly for solution

Comment: it doesn't allow me to upload more than 3 images. but basic i want to show  the list of subcategory  including the category name

Answer (score 0):

```
$stmt="SELECT * 
FROM {{sub_categories}} 
LEFT JOIN {{category}} ON 
{{sub_categories}}.cat_id={{category}}.cat_id
 WHERE
 {{sub_categories}}.merchant_id={{category}}.merchant_id
ORDER BY {{sub_categories}}.cat_id DESC";
```